# Why does a nullable object not have a HasValue method?

Tags: c#

I have:

```
Module? module = project.getModule(ModuleName);
if (module.HasValue)
{
    /// some code
}
```

I get an error "'Module' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue' and no accessible extension method 'HasValue' accepting a first argument of type 'Module' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

But `module` is a nullable type. Why does it not have a HasValue method?

Comment: Is `Module` a reference type by any chance?

Comment: There's a difference between a `Nullable<T>` as a type that permits non-nullable things like ints to exhibit "no value" behavior, and `#nullable` as a compile-time checking of "might this variable be null, and has the dev made any effort to prevent going down a route of using it without having first made sure it's not null". In other words, your code should be `if(module != null) ///some code` - if you just straight do e.g `Console.WriteLine(module.Name)` you get a green wiggly saying "module might be null here" but if you've guarded against it with e.g. an if or certain value, no wiggly.